# Rigify cannot rotate head anymore

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, rigify

I have the following problem with my Rigify rig. When i rotate the headbone in pose mode the mesh does not rotate with the bone anymore. I can still move the bone and the head deforms, but it does not rotate. If i rotate the neck bone, the head rotates with it just fine.
It still works on an older version of my model so there must be something messed up.

What i tried:
Checking the weight paint.
Messing around with Neck follow and Head follow.
Looking around for possible differences between the old and the new model.

If someone has any idea what could cause this, please let me now.

[image: Picture of rotation]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Here is the file @moonboots [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2EQJv2le" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2EQJv2le/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try that. First thing display the layers with the important bones:

[image]

Switch to *Pose* mode, the bone called *MCH-STR-neck* has a *Stretch To* constraint which makes the head stretch when you move the controller bone called head, is it what you want? If not, disable this constraint.

[image]

Now to make the bone called *DEF-head* rotate you could give it a *Copy Rotation* constraint with the bone called *head* as target:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked. Comparing this to the old rig, it seems like i somehow deleted the constraint. The old rig uses a copy transform with ORG-spine.006 as target. Copy transform and copy rotation both work.